# Avro ByteBuffer.allocate java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null

Tags: java, avro, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to send data via Kinesis stream in Avro format. But I've run into issue - IllegalArgumentException is occurred al the time, here is my code:

**user.avsc**

```
{
    "doc": "User schema",
    "namespace": "avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "name", "type": "string"}
    ]
}
```

**Producer:**

```
User user = User.newBuilder().setName("Igor").build()
byte[] bytes = toAvro(user); 


kinesis.putRecord(
                    new PutRecordRequest()
                            .withStreamName(streamName)
                            .withData(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes))
                            .withPartitionKey("test_partition_key")
            );

private static byte[] toAvro(GenericContainer obj) throws IOException {
        DatumWriter datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter();
        byte[] bytes;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); DataFileWriter dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter(datumWriter)) {
            dataFileWriter.create(obj.getSchema(), baos);
            dataFileWriter.append(obj);
            dataFileWriter.flush();
            baos.flush();
            bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        }
        System.out.println(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return bytes;
    }
```

**Consumer:**

```
public class DefaultRecordProcessor implements IRecordProcessor {
  @Override
    public void processRecords(List<Record> records, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
        System.out.println("Processing " + records.size() + " records");
        List<String> data = records.stream()
                .map(Record::getData)
                .map(d -> new String(d.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
                .map(this::convert)
                .collect(toList());
    }

private GenericData convert(String data) {
 SpecificData specificData = new SpecificData();

           GenericData result = null;
            DatumReader<GenericData> datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(null, schema, specificData);
            DataFileReader<GenericData> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(new SeekableByteArrayInput(data.getBytes()), datumReader);
            while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
                result = dataFileReader.next(result);
            }
            return result;
}

}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:288)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.<init>(DataFileReader.java:97)
```

I've found a very similar issue, but it did not help me - [Error when querying avro-backed hive table: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727987/error-when-querying-avro-backed-hive-table-java-lang-illegalargumentexception)

**UPDATE:**
but if I don't transfer data via Kinesis stream it works correctly:

```
GenericContainer data = User.newBuilder().setName("Igor").build();

        // write
        DatumWriter datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(data.getSchema(), new SpecificData());
        byte[] bytes;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); DataFileWriter dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter(datumWriter)) {
            dataFileWriter.create(data.getSchema(), baos);
            dataFileWriter.append(data);
            dataFileWriter.flush();
            baos.flush();
            bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        }
        System.out.println(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // read
        SpecificData specificData = new SpecificData();
        Object result = null;
        DatumReader datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(null, data.getSchema(), specificData);
        DataFileReader dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(new SeekableByteArrayInput(bytes), datumReader);
        while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
            result = dataFileReader.next(result);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
bjavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"User","namespace":"avro","doc":"User schema","fields":[{"name":"name","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}}]}������ &�4^�[l

    Igor������ &�4^�[l
    {"name": "Igor"}
```

but from the other side if I set the data directly:

```
bytes = "Obj\u0001\u0002\u0016avro.schema�\u0002{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"namespace\":\"avro\",\"doc\":\"User schema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}}]}\u0000z4v܉I��PJ19���#\u0002\n".getBytes();
```

I still get the error

Comment: This part looks suspicious to me: `.map(d -> new String(d.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))` You take byte array, convert to string with UTF-8 encoding, then get bytes again to process avro. Just pass bytes directly.

Comment: yeah, that's true, I've figured it out. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was occurred due to byte[] to String conversion.

```
List<String> data = records.stream()
                .map(Record::getData)
                .map(d -> new String(d.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
                .map(this::convert)
                .collect(toList());
```

**map(d -> new String(d.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))**

I removed that part and process data as byte[] and it works.